# Link cabal to local library

Tags: haskell, cabal

Lets `MyLib` be my local Haskell library. I can build it with `cabal build` and install it with `cabal install`, but can I use it in other projects **without** the installation step?

I'm developing several libraries and installing them after every change is not a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have two entirely separate projects, one called `my-library` and another called `my-project`. And `my-project` depends on `my-library`.

The way to build `my-library` and make it available to other projects is `cabal install my-library`. Once that's done, any other project can use the library.

Now you're ready to build `my-project` using the command `cabal install my-project`. It will *not* rebuild or reinstall `my-library`, but it will link your project with the library.

Now, if you make modifications to `my-library`, be sure to *update the version number* before running `cabal install my-library`. If you forget to bump the version number, you will be warned that `my-project` will be made obsolete. Now the old version and the new version of your library are available to other projects.

You can continue to run your projects. They will happily *continue to use the previous version* of `my-library` *until* you do another `cabal install my-project`. So there is no need to re-install everything after every change.

If you do want to rebuild your projects, but continue to work with an older version of your library, you can specify that in the `build-depends` section of your cabal file. For example, if you have versions 1.0 and 2.0 of `my-library` installed, you can build your project against the older version like this:

```
build-depends: my-library==1.0, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a great solution to your problem, but you can use sandboxes to keep your development environment a bit cleaner.

With cabal-1.18 or newer, you can create a sandbox with `cabal sandbox init` and then you can either install to that sandbox or add-source (`cabal sandbox add-source <path to library>`).

This helps to keep unstable libraries (and their potentially unstable dependencies) out of your user package database, and that can help prevent 'cabal hell' (unsolvable conflicts between dependencies).  However, that doesn't **directly** help reduce the number of commands you need to issue each time you want to do a top-level build.

What you **can** do though, is set up a simple script that performs the add-source commands and builds your top-level package. eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
cabal sandbox init # a no-op if the sandbox exists.
cabal sandbox add-source ../MyLib
cabal install --dependencies-only
cabal build
```

Granted, you could do that before, but this time you can also easily clean up (removing all the installed artifacts) by cleaning the sandbox:

```
cabal sandbox delete
```